# Slideshare API: get_slideshows_by_tag method doesn't return my slideshows

Tags: linkedin-api

The Slideshare API's "get_slideshows_by_tag" method is never finding any of my slideshows. Has someone got this to work and is there anything I could be missing here ?

My url looks like this: 
https://www.slideshare.net/api/2/get_slideshows_by_tag?tag=argo&api_key=MYAPIKEY&ts=1455713883&hash=9cb007d02a47442df1c8b54b40d69bdef3a39874

The response looks like this:

```
<Tag>
<Name>argo</Name>
<Count>0</Count>
</Tag>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the same thing. I think LinkedIn has given up on the SlideShare API.